# How to concat SURF descriptors for Flann Index with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, concatenation, descriptor

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and OpenCV 2.4.10.

I create descriptors for each image of my database and stored in a `CList` of `Mat*`.
then I have to create one global descriptor for the flann index.

My question is how to merge, concat these descriptors for Flann Index.

This is what I do:

```
Mat*ConcatDescriptors(CList<Mat*, Mat*> *descsList) { 

    POSITION position = descsList->GetHeadPosition();

    Mat* concatedDescs = new Mat();//the final descriptor
    position = descsList->GetHeadPosition();

    while (position)
    {       
        concatedDescs->push_back(descsList->GetNext(position));
    }

    descsList->RemoveAll();
    return concatedDescs;
}
```

The final result is just a value repeated in a vector.

Comment: just as a sidenote - please avoid using pointers to cv::Mat. use references or copies(of the Mat header). it is a smartpointer already, and not meant to be used with pointers. also you probably wanted to push a cv::Mat to concatenatedDesc, not a pointer to it.

Comment: what about vconcat from opencv?

Comment: " The size of the matrix is num_features x feature_dimensionality " - so, rather hconcat.

Comment: using Mat instead of Mat* solved the problem using the same code.